# What does "Error starting process" could mean in my case?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I was learning C++ coding on Eclipse and I made a little Cash Register program and help you calculate how much change you should give in dollars and quarters and dimes and pennies.

When I tried to run it, it always gives me this error message:

> `'Launching XXX.exe' has encountered a problem. Error Starting process.`
>   [image: Error message]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double askprice(double&);


int main()
{
// Todo place code here
    double price;
    double total=0;
    char answer='y';
    double cashin;
    double change;
    int dollar;
    int qt;
    int dm;
    int ct;


    cout<<"Do you have more items? y/n"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    while (answer == 'y')
    {
        askprice(price);
        total=total+price;

    }
    cout<<"How much do you pay?"<<endl;
    cin>>cashin;
    change=cashin-total;
    dollar = change;
    int intchange = change*100;
    qt = intchange%100/25;
    dm = intchange*100%25/10;
    ct = intchange*100%10;

    cout<<"Your change is "<<dollar<<" dollars "<<qt<<" quarters "<<dm<<" dimes and "<<ct<<" cents."<<endl;

return (0);
}

double askprice(double price)
{
    cout<<"Enter the price of your item"<<endl;
    cin>>price;
    return price;
}
```

[(here as image if you prefer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0eeA.png)

Does anyone can give me an incentive about what could I do wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem, and mention error messages verbatim in your question.

Comment: "I don't think it's something wrong with my coding" - *most* people with a bit of experience would think the opposite. Bugs in the code *you* wrote is usually the most likely source of the error.

Comment: @A.L. The compiler errors occur only if the code you wrote can't be compiled into executable. And not all programs that can be compiled into executable, run without errors. You can't expect compiler to hold your hand on every step.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So you think it's the code? hmm... Let me check it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. Sorry if I came a bit ignorant  : (  .I will make a note on that. I said that because there is no error message on my code lines. Only two warning saying that I converted a double into an int. But I did that on purpose. Other than that there is no red lines anywhere. Therefore I thought maybe it is my MinGW?

Comment: @A.L. the compiler is not required to provide warnings or errors for every wrong construct or undefined behaviour. The absense of compiler warnings/errors in *no way* means that your program is bug free. It's on *you* to follow the rules of the language; the compiler just helps in *some* cases.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see. Thank you so much for your instructions. I will try my best to diagnose the problem. Thanks again for your kindness.

Comment: It looks to me like you have two different versions of the "askprice" function.  Read the material in your book about NOT writing ambiguous code that the compiler has to figure out.  You have a prototype for one version and a definition for another version...which is the compiler supposed to use???

Comment: @A.L. _So you think it's the code?_ I didn't say that. I was responding to _I said that because there is no error message on my code lines._

Comment: @Drt That is a problem. Thank you for pointing it out. But the error still exists after I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time struggling with my code, I did find lots of problems with it. Thanks to @Arthur, @Jesper Juhl, @Algirdas Preidžius and @Dr t. I have a lot to learn. Thank you guys.

But the error message turned out to be unrelated to the code itself. I fixed the bugs in my code, created a new project and copied the code into the new project. And it ran perfectly. After checking the "Run Configuration" of my original code, I found that in the "C/C++ Application:" it was the directory of my c++ source file, where it should be (I erased the directory and typed manually)"Debug/Cash register.exe". "Cash register" is the name of my project. And the error message disappeared. I still don't know exactly the logic behind it. But the problem was solved. If someone would like to explain it to me, I would appreciate it. Thanks again to this amazing community.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
double askprice(double price);
```

for

```
double askprice(double&);
```